# Configure WCF service client with certificate authentication programmatically

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security, wcf-binding, wcf-client

How do i setup a ServiceClient using Certificate authentication programmatically in c#?
And i don't want to use .config.

```
       using(var srv = GetServiceInstance())
       {
            srv.DoStuff()
        }

        private  TheServiceClient GetServiceInstance()
        {
            var service = new TheServiceClient(CreateWsHttpBinding(), CreateEndpointAdress());
            return service;
        }
        private static WSHttpBinding CreateWsHttpBinding()
        {
        var wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
        wsHttpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;

        wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
        wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.Realm = "";
        wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

        wsHttpBinding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
        wsHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;

        wsHttpBinding.Name = "Bindingname";
        wsHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        wsHttpBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        wsHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        wsHttpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        wsHttpBinding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        wsHttpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
        wsHttpBinding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
        wsHttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
        wsHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536;
        wsHttpBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
        wsHttpBinding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        wsHttpBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
        wsHttpBinding.AllowCookies = false;

        wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
        wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 16384;
        wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8192;
        wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096;
        wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384;

        wsHttpBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
        wsHttpBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        wsHttpBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = false;

        return wsHttpBinding;
    }
        private static EndpointAddress CreateEndpointAdress()
        {
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "CN=Certname", false)[0];
            store.Close();

        var endpointIdentity = EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(cert);
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("ServiceUri"), endpointIdentity);

        return endpoint;
    }
```

So this is what i have so far!
Using this returns an error saying :

> The client certificate is not provided. Specify a client certificate
>   in ClientCredentials.

Anyone have an idea? Be gentle, I'm new to this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As discovered in comments on the other answer, you need to set `service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate` directly.

Answer (score 0):

may need to see if that certificate is visible to the machine account - assuming you've debugged to the following point:

`var cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "CN=Certname", false)[0];`

and it is saying it can't find it?

Comment: the cert is found and set. service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate is null

Comment: Aren't you meant to set `service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate` directly? It's documented as read-write, and for other forms of client authentication, I've set e.g. `ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName` and `ClientCredentials.UserName.Password` directly before. I think the `EndpointIdentity` stuff is for service endpoints, not clients.

Comment: That is what i figured out also. When i put `service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "CN=CertName", false)[0];` In the GetServiceInstance method it worked. I also needed to keep the EndpointIdentity where i added `var endpointIdentity = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("DnsIdentity");`

Comment: @Anton your comment was very helpful. If you post your comment as ananswer i will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing Contract description. Here, is a little example about how to do it. If you have further problem, I have full working code. I will help you.

```
ContractDescription Contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IEvalService), typeof(EvalServiceClient));
```

You have to initialize with the client before opening the proxy. Hope it will work.

have fun